# Loop along a column of a dataframe with conditional sentence

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements, counter

I have the following dataset:

```
FO.1  Pilot T.O
VAM   F
CAM   F
LYA   C
FRZ   F
DYN   F
VAM   F
VAM   C
CAM   F
```

I would like to run a loop along the `FO#1` column and `Pilot T/O` column. The loop needs to identify each FO#1 and if Pilot T/O is F or C. For example, if FO#1 is VAF the result should show me how many times the Pilot T/O takes the value of F or C.

I have tried the following:

```
#Loading the dataset
test2 <- read.xlsx(file = 'test.xlsx', 1)
#Count
count=0
#Loop across the elements of FO.1 column
for (i in test2$FO.1)
{
#Conditional sentence to check if the element takes the value F
  if (test2$Pilot.T.O[i] == 'F')
  {
  #We add 1 to the count
  count[i] <- count+1
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error in if (test2$Pilot.T.O[i] == "F") { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: You have probably `NA` in test2$Pilot.T.O. Please try to add `& !is.na(test2$Pilot.T.O[i])`

Comment: Please also show the structure of the data.

Comment: @Clemsang there are no NA :(

Comment: @RomanLuštrik data added :)

Comment: Use `i in 1:length(test2$FO.1)`

Comment: @Clemsang this cleared the error! However, I think the code is still not working...

Comment: count is not a vector, dont use `[i]`

Comment: @Clemsang each single pilot (e.g.VAM) should have it's own count depending on the times he has a F. Should be a vector no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

- solution 1: using `sapply()`+`table()`

```
res <- sapply(c("C","F"), function(x) table(df)[,x])
```

such that

```
> res
    C F
CAM 0 2
DYN 0 1
FRZ 0 1
LYA 1 0
VAM 1 2
```

or just `res <- table(df)`

```
> res
     Pilot T.O
FO.1  C F
  CAM 0 2
  DYN 0 1
  FRZ 0 1
  LYA 1 0
  VAM 1 2
```

- solution 2: using `split()` + `table()`

```
res <- Map(table,split(df,df$FO.1))
```

such that

```
> res
$CAM
     Pilot T.O
FO.1  F
  CAM 2

$DYN
     Pilot T.O
FO.1  F
  DYN 1

$FRZ
     Pilot T.O
FO.1  F
  FRZ 1

$LYA
     Pilot T.O
FO.1  C
  LYA 1

$VAM
     Pilot T.O
FO.1  C F
  VAM 1 2
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(FO.1 = c("VAM", "CAM", "LYA", "FRZ", "DYN", "VAM", 
"VAM", "CAM"), `Pilot T.O` = c("F", "F", "C", "F", "F", "F", 
"C", "F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: `table(df)[,"F"]` is the wanted result

Comment: @Clemsang thanks for comments, I updated my answer with your feedback